# Read temperature with Arduino ATmega328P ADC with DTH11

Tags: arduino, embedded, temperature, adc

I have a little problem for school and I have to read the temperature with Arduino from a DTH11 sensor and print it in serial, only in C language.
Can someone help me with an example or something.

Comment: The DTH11 has a digital single-wire serial interface - the ADC is of no use to you with this sensor.  Really all you are asking here if for someone to Google it for you:  https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-interface-Humidity-and-Temperature-DTH11-Se/

Answer (score 2):

You can find the DHT11 data sheet on the Internet, for example

https://akizukidenshi.com/download/ds/aosong/DHT11.pdf
or

https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf

there are sections which explain how the sensor module communicates via 1 wire with the MCU (Arduino).

Then, once you have an idea how the communication happens, you can read more articles like

https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/dht11-dht22-sensors-temperature-and-humidity-tutorial-using-arduino/

and there are many others, most use an already written library.

If your assignment won't let you use a library, you'll have to read for example the code at https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DHTLib/ in files `dht.h` and `dht.cpp` and implement your own, maybe minimal version based on your understanding of the information provided on DHT's data sheet.

I would recommend to get things working by using a library first, then change it to work without.